# move the result of query from one server to another server

Tags: python, mysql

I want to create the result of select query from the `localhost` with the port `3306` into another `localhost` with the port number `3308`. The query is the data dictionary on the source server into a `table in another server`.

```
rdcursur.execute("CREATE TABLE dd_rd_{0} SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS "
                         "ENGINE=FEDERATED cONNECTION='MYSQL://root:2222@127.0.0.1:3306/{1}/{0}'".formate(v,key))
#v is the name of table and key is the name of database. for example in static way we can use sakila database and actor table.  

rdcursur.execute("CREATE TABLE dd_rd_{0} SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS "
                         "ENGINE=FEDERATED cONNECTION='MYSQL://root:2222@127.0.0.1:3306/sakila/actor'")
```

But it doesn't work. could you please help me.